# How can I splice a string by using the find function?

Tags: c++, string, splice

Right now, I'm making a quiz where my program reads from a .txt file. I can use `getline` to read the answers from the .txt using `fstream`. For example, I have the the string "A. greater B. equal C. less D. invalid"

I've named the `string` containing this read line `answers`

I would like it so that each one of my answers `A. greater`, `B. equal`, `C. less`, `D. invalid` are each put on a separate line. Would the find function work okay here? So far, I haven't had much success.

I should mention that I do get a slight error when using `size_t` and `find`. For example, when trying to get question D, I would do this:

```
size_t posD = question.find("D.");
string strD = question.substr(posD);
string test(strD, question.end());
```

But, I get an error that says "no instance of constructor matches the argument list" on `strD`. Is there a fix?

Cheers

Comment: Yes `find` would work fine. Start by finding a part of the string. Then splice it. Then rinse+repeat for all others.

Comment: *Would the find function work okay here?* I would think yes. *So far, I haven't had much success.* Post what you have tried and indicate where you think you are running into problems.

Comment: YOu are vastly overcomplicating the problem.  It is often better to ask how to achieve and effect than to ask how to implement what you have decided is a solution.  For example you could include newlines in the string:  `string answers = "A. greater\nB. equal\nC. less\nD. invalid";` or use an array of strings: `string answers[] = {"A. greater",  "B. equal", "C. less", "D. invalid";`, then print in a loop.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, but I am reading from a long .txt file and the format of the answers are in that way

Comment: In what world can `getline` be used to _display_ anything, or for that matter `find()` _splice_ anything?  The first is an _input_ function, and the second is a `const` function and cannot modify the object.  Moreover "_splicing_" is not the operation you are asking about there - to _splice_ means to _join two ends_; here you clearly want to _split_.

Comment: @Clifford I am reading from a .txt file using `fstream`. I'll edit that

Comment: @LukeZhang : Not in the example in your question you are not; you show an assignment with a literal string const.

Comment: @Clifford Okay, edited that once more

Comment: Your `no instance of constructor...` issue is a separate question - avoid asking unrelated questions in one post.  The "duplicate" question does not answer that question, and now it is closed you'll have to ask again in any event.  The object `test` would require a constructor `std::string( size_t, std::string::iterator )` which is not defined, and makes little sense; what do you think `std::string::end()` does?